# Https сервер на c++

Tags: c++, linux, веб-сервер, https

Нужно написать простой https сервер на c++ на linux, который будет принимать и отправлять post запросы. Можете пожалуйста дать пример, или хотя бы ссылку на сайт библиотеки с примером.

Comment: Могу посоветовать [Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Answer (score 3):

Вот две хорошие библиотеки:

- https://github.com/pocoproject/poco
- https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion

А вот неплохая статья:
https://habr.com/post/217437/

P.S. 
Еще одна библиотека

http://wolkykim.github.io/libasyncd/

И пример кода на ней (по ссылке подробнее посмотрите)

```
int my_http_get_handler(short event, ad_conn_t *conn, void *userdata) {
    if (ad_http_get_status(conn) == AD_HTTP_REQ_DONE) {
        ad_http_response(conn, 200, "text/html", "Hello World", 11);
        return AD_DONE; // Keep connection alive.
    }
    return AD_OK;
}

int my_http_default_handler(short event, ad_conn_t *conn, void *userdata) {
    if (ad_http_get_status(conn) == AD_HTTP_REQ_DONE) {
        ad_http_response(conn, 501, "text/html", "Not implemented", 15);
        return AD_CLOSE; // Close connection.
    }
    return AD_OK;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ad_log_level(AD_LOG_DEBUG);
    ad_server_t *server = ad_server_new();
    ad_server_set_option(server, "server.port", "8888");
    ad_server_set_option(server, "server.ssl_cert", "ssl.cert");
    ad_server_set_option(server, "server.ssl_pkey", "ssl.pkey")
    ad_server_register_hook(server, ad_http_handler, NULL); // HTTP Parser is also a hook.
    ad_server_register_hook_on_method(server, "GET", my_http_get_handler, NULL);
    ad_server_register_hook(server, my_http_default_handler, NULL);

    return ad_server_start(server);
}
```

Comment: В этой стать про http, а мне нужен https. Если Вам не сложно можете пример сделать?

Comment: @Кирилл отредактировал ответ.